# how can i delete rails object,each do information

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to show one of object in show page

I made controller show method

```
def show
    @setoff_histories = SettlementSetoffHistory.where(PAYMENT_CNCL_AFT_SEQ: params[:id])
end
```

and use .each to display in show page

```
<%= @setoff_histories.each do |t| %>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><strong>setoff history</strong></div>
    <div class="col-sm-7"><%= t.PAYMENT_CNCL_AFT_SEQ %></div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQApM.png)

why this object information displayed? how can i delete it?
I my rails version is 5.2.2

thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the loop code from <%= to <%, so remove the = sign. That = prints code to the page, you want it to process ruby code and run the loop.

```
<% @setoff_histories.each do |t| %>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><strong>setoff history</strong></div>
    <div class="col-sm-7"><%= t.PAYMENT_CNCL_AFT_SEQ %></div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```